# Android What is difference between device state after screen timeout vs. sleep?

Tags: android

What is the exact effect of a screen timeout?   Does the device go into sleep mode? What exact state is the device in during screen timeout?  If I do  Settings.System.putInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1);    set to one second will this put the device in sleep mode in 1 second? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing of all, you should know that "turning off the screen" != "sleep mode". Since you may listen to some music or download some games with large size while the screen is off, but the CPU is still running to do these jobs, therefore it's not in "sleep mode."

As a result, sleep mode is defined as a mode that the CPU is idle. While the system is in sleep mode, the time spent in this mode is not counted in the device uptime (the device uptime can be obtained by calling `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`). Let's answer the questions:

1) Turning off the screen.

2) No.

3) A state that the screen is off.

4) No. Setting screen timeout to one second means that if no action is taken on the device for one second, the device will turn off the screen automatically. Even the screen is turned off, the device is also not in sleep mode.

Comment: Is screen autoshutdown the same as sleep?

Comment: I'll credit your answer, but please indicate how shutdown compares to sleep since that was the question.